# publish english Alexa Skill in Germany?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I've just finished creating my first Alexa Skill. It explains rules about a board game, that is only available in English. The game is also played in Germany, so I want to make the skill available in the german Skill Store.

It does not make sense to translate the skill into German, because then a german user, having a question about "void spiders" mentioned in the rulebook, would have to translate "void spiders" into German, and I'd have to guess how the user would translate it in order to process his requests.

I assume that I can't make the skill available in the german Skill Store, but only in countries where Alexa speaks English, and if a german user wants to use the skill, they have to change their Alexas country setting? Or is there a better option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a skill available in the German Skill Store if it is not available in German. To publish a skill in a store the following must be true:

> Customers can access *all skills* that meet *all* of the following [according to documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/launch-your-skill.html):
>
> - The skill is distributed in their country or region.
> - The skill supports the language selected for their Alexa-enabled device.
> - The skill supports the primary language for the country or region in which the customer's device is registered. This determines whether the skill is available in the skill store. For example:
>
>   - A skill must have an English (US) version to be available to customers who registered their devices with the .com site.
>   - A skill must have a German version to be available to customers who registered their devices with the .de site.

However, all languages of your skill will be available in that store. So if that user has their device set to English (US) they will be able to consume your content in that language. Unfortunately, this setting is set per device and not per skill.